# Geoxml-V3 icon request path repeated in request

Tags: google-maps, kml, geoxml

Im trying to migrate form geoxml to geoxml-v3 and also google maps v2 to v3. The issue I'm having is with geoxml-v3. The icon request generated on the client from geoxml-v3 is garbeled. For example

```
localhost/app/resources/icon.png
```

will become something like

```
localhost/app/resources/app/resources/app/resources/app/resources/icon.png
```

These kml files work with geoxml and are correctly formed. The style icon segment is

```
<Style id="off-red">
 <IconStyle>
  <Icon>
   <href>resources/icon.png</href>
  </Icon>
 </IconStyle>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out its a problem with geoxml-v3 library, well at least in my circumstance where I want to store my own marker icons. There is some code, line 386

```
if (typeof this.url == "string")
```

which prefixes the icon url with the current context or else the last used context. Didn't look into it to much. Commenting out that if block will lead to correct request.

This is a hack but works for my requirements.